# Screenshots for iTunes Connect with wrong aspect ratio

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot, app-store-connect, screen-size

Took screenshots for every size in the simulator and I'm having a problem with 4.7-inch (iphone 6) and 5.5-inch (iphone 6 Plus) screenshots only.... With 4-inch and 3.5-inch had no problem uploading.

Error states: **One or more screenshots have the wrong aspect ratio. For more information, see the Developer Guide.**

On the Dev-Guide says:

```
4.7-inch -> 750 x 1334 pixels for hi-res portrait
5.5-inch -> 1242 x 2208 pixels for hi-res portrait
```

My screenshots HAVE those dimensions, I took them with the respective simulators. Any one had a similar problem?

(Already tried renaming the screenshots, avoiding strange characters and what not... No success yet)

Comment: I'm having same problem right now.  The same images worked fine a few days ago, so it looks like iTunes Connect has temporarily lost its mind.

Comment: Yeah, at least it seems we're not alone in this, already sent an issue to Apple contact center, seems like we're just gonna have to wait :(

Comment: I am having the issue with images that I successfully submitted earlier in the day. This is an iTunes Connect issue. I've submitted a support request--I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now.

Comment: Same here, only happens for iPhone 6/6+.

Comment: Yep same here. Emailed apple and they said they had engineers looking at it

Comment: I can't believe how buggy the new iTunes Connect is. This is not the first issue I've had with it. Other 500 server error issue was resolved by me using Safari instead of Chrome..

Comment: I am having this issue right now.

Comment: @AmitNivedanKalra are you taking the screenshots from the respective simulator (Cmd+s)? Back then this was caused by a temporary bug in iTunes Connect

Answer (score 9):

set the simulator scale to 100%

Simulator > Window > Scale > 100%

Comment: ^^This does provide the answer. It saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question if you already have a screenshot that needs fixing. I shouldn't have to spend £1k on a Mac so I can retake a screenshot...

Answer (score 3):

It's been a temporary problem by Apple. Now it should accept your images: [Uploading screenshots to iTunes connect for iPhone 6 and 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028272/uploading-screenshots-to-itunes-connect-for-iphone-6-and-6)

Comment: Still getting the same issue with 4.7inch screenshots

Answer (score 3):

Just rename them to "1.png" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Simulator began scaling images. If you're scaling is anything other than 100, change it back to 100. I had the same issue, this seemed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run your app on the simulator, and save screen shots.
2. Rename those screen shots to 4.7.1 (iPhone 6), 5.5.1 (iPhone 6 plus) and so on.

Comment: Do you honestly believe that's all it takes?

Comment: Why would **I** need to try it? I'm not the OP and I can't believe that you honestly believe this would just work doing these steps.