# iTunes Connect error on iphone 6 plus screenshots

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

iTunes connect returns an error when I upload a screenshot for the iPhone 6 plus (5.5 screen). The errors states that image dimensions are wrong. However, the image is a screenshot captured from the XCode simulator and I've verified the image is 1242 x 2208 (in OS X Finder, Preview, and GIMP).

What's the missing secret handshake here?

Comment: Apparently others having identical issue now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027567/screenshots-for-itunes-connect-with-wrong-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a temporary error on Apple's side. You should be able to upload your images now: [Uploading screenshots to iTunes connect for iPhone 6 and 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028272/uploading-screenshots-to-itunes-connect-for-iphone-6-and-6)

Comment: Works now. Wish Apple had some notification system, so I didn't burn time trying to resolve.