# Uploading screenshots to iTunes connect for iPhone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store-connect, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I'm trying to upload screenshots of my app on iPhone 6 and 6+ and I'm getting a baffling error message:

"One or more screenshots are the wrong size..", see the screenshot below

[image: Error message]

However, I have checked the apple website and the required size is 750x1334 and 1242x2208

In an attempt to prove I'm not going nuts, screenshot of the properties below.

[image: Properties]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This a big problem, I also can't upload screenshots for both 4.7 and 5.5  (I've check them 3 times and they are correct).

Same message as yours.

The error on **6 Plus** side is caused by the fact that **itunesconnect wants 1242 x 2208** screenshots for portrait and 2208 x 1242 in landscape.

** Update.. Ok, it seems to work now.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this problem when using screenshots from the Simulator. Solution: Make sure that the scale is 100% (Window->Scale in simulator menu). If you scale the window down (common when simulating hight resolution devices), then the screenshot will also be scaled down...

Answer (score 8):

I have this issue right now. This answer helped me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052482/2764408

`Just rename them to "1.png" and so on.`

It may sounds insane but when I renamed the simulator screenshots to 1.png, 2.png and so on, itunesconnect uploaded them without any errors

UPDATE:
I think that non latin symbols in the filename are the reason of this problem. iOS simulator uses localized date in the screenshot file names.

Answer (score 5):

I'm experiencing the same problem.

Apple just replied, they have new rules, you have to upload your build first. Absolute nonsense.

Sent them link to this thread, problem is on their server side.

UPD: now fixed for me as well. :)

Comment: So typical Apple, world richest company but they can't get the basics right. Wasted 30+ minutes of my time.

Comment: Hah! I've cheerfully entered the 3rd hour of banging head against keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 'simple' way

1. go on check the image size for a particular screenshot  https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925
2. open your screenshot with preview
3. modify the size to based on what apple wants [adjust image size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKsaC.png)
4. then thats it hope you will find it easy

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your screenshots in Preview application
2. Go to Tools -> Assign ProfilE
3. Choose **sRGB IEC61966-2.1**
4. Press OK
5. Then submit your screenshots to Appstore Connects

its fixed for me!.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue but that was regarding ipad..soo for people who wants 12.9 inch display screenshots to be uploaded..is to select ipad pro as simulator and capture screensho using file and save screenshot and it gets saved on your desktop..just rename the screenshot with 1.png or etc..n upload.....it vl solve ypur problem